# Firebase Storage: the uploaded image doesn't saved on the app

Tags: firebase, swift3, xcode8, firebase-storage

I upload the image via .Camera to Firebase Storage. When I closed app and run again, this image don't saved at my app. I know that I missed something. Please, tell me what I should to add. Thank's a lot!
This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage

class PicturesOfCoinsViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        saveOneEuroCentImage()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var oneEuroCentImage: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func usePhotoButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        picker.delegate = self
    }

    func saveOneEuroCentImage() {

        let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("userPictures/oneEuroCent.jpg")

        if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.oneEuroCentImage.image!) {

            storageRef.put(uploadData, metadata: nil) {(metadata, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        oneEuroCentImage.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a persistent copy of the image on your app then you must save the photo to your apps document directory before the upload. From your code above you are only uploading it to your cloud storage in firebase but there is no code for saving your picture locally, thats why it does not exist when the app is run again.
I suggest you create a documents directory file path or url for the image and then save it.

```
  let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let path = paths.first
let imageFolderPath = path?.appending("MyFBImages")
if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: imageFolderPath!){
    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: imageFolderPath!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: [:])
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
let imageFilePath = imageFolderPath?.appending("myImageName.jpg")
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(), 1)
do {
    try imageData?.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: imageFilePath!))
} catch let error {
     print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

N/B : the imageData in the code you can get that from the image you created just before the upload to firebase.
This should help you save your image locally. Next time you run your app you can access your previous images by initializing UIImage from contents of the url that holds your saved photos.
I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Hi! I added your code, but Image doesn't saved. I'm new at swift and I ask you to help. I think I should my UIImage = path to the document directory. But I don't know how this write. (I added your code to func saveOneEuroCentImage() {

Comment: Okay, I can be of help to you, mail me @ lordstuny@gmail.com.